# We roll a 6-sided die n times. What is the probability that all faces have appeared on top face?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

i tried it like this:

we need 6 places to put the $ 1,2,3,4,5,6 $ numbers on top face and in rest of the places we don't care.

So number of favorable cases is

$$ ^nC_6*6!*6^{n-6}$$

My total number of cases are $6^n $  So my probability is $$ ^nC_6*6!*6^{n-6}/6^n$$

but it's wrong. where am i wrong?

Comment: What does "we need 6 places to put 1,2,3,4,5,6 numbers" mean?

Comment: I think the problem is that when you say "in rest of the places we don't care" you are inevitably allowing for double+ counting of the number of favorable cases.

Comment: See [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). In this case we have six coupons.

Comment: You can use inclusion-exclusion also by defining $P_i$ as the number of strings missing $i$, $P_{ij}$ as the number of strings missing both $i$ and $j$ and so on, where $i,j \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: You can also skip some steps and use the final result written in terms of stirling numbers of the second kind, giving a final answer of $\dfrac{\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\6\end{smallmatrix}\right\}6!}{6^n}$, but if you've never used stirling numbers of the second kind or proven any results surrounding them, you should go through the inclusion-exclusion approach at least once.

Comment: hi arthur, coupon collector problem is opposite of this, in this case we roll n times and we need to find out the probability that all faces have been appeared. but in coupon collector we need to find out the number of rolls untill we have seen all the faces , correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Your solution overcounts desired cases:  for example $(1,2,3,4,5,6,1)$ will be counted twice - once where you choose the first six places and do not care about the last and again when you choose the last six places and do not care about the first

Comment: Hi,@JMoravitz , basically what you have done is you chose 6 places out of n where you put 1 to 6 so that you can ensure that all faces have been appeared but what about rest n-6 places, each should be filled with 6 ways?

Comment: i got it , Thanks @Henry

Comment: I edited a bit. Please roll back if it is not what you wished to say..

Comment: @KKumar No, Stirling numbers of the second kind written as $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$ are not the same as binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$.  Stirling numbers of the second kind count the number of ways to partition an $n$ element set into $k$ unlabeled nonempty subsets.  I chose a way to partition the $n$ positions in the sequence into $6$ nonempty subsets, and then I decided which part in the partition was to be used for each of the face's numbers.